# Base64 encode multiline github actions output

Tags: github-actions

I have a github actions that output de kubeconfig file from pulumi.

I need to encode this output in base64 in order to use it with the kubectl github actions.

```
- run: echo "KUBE_CONFIG=$(echo -n ${{ steps.pulumi.outputs.kubeconfig }} | base64 -w 0)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

which outputs this in terminal :

```
Run echo "KUBE_CONFIG=$(echo -n ***
  echo "KUBE_CONFIG=$(echo -n ***
  ***
  ***
    ***
      ***
      ***
  ***
  ***
    ***
      ***
      ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
    ***
      *** | base64 -w 0)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}

/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 19: ***: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 20: -: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 21: ***: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 22: certificate-authority-data:: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 23: server:: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 24: ***: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 25: -: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 26: ***: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 27: ***: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 28: ***: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 29: current-***: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 30: kind:: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 31: preferences:: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 32: ***: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 33: -: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 34: ***: command not found
/home/runner/work/_temp/9a9ee730-fca6-4f3a-b24b-14bc4b831fcf.sh: line 35: token:: command not found
```

How can I encode this output in base64 ?

Comment: The [syntax to store multiline variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings) is a bit different according to the official documentation. Did you try it that way?

Comment: Try: `echo "KUBE_CONFIG=$(base64 -w 0 <<< '${{ steps.pulumi.outputs.kubeconfig }}')" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

Comment: I ended up encoding in base64 in my pulumi program.